# AngularJS - jQuery not called while using jCrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jcrop

**Scripts and CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v2.0.0-RC1/css/Jcrop.min.css" />
<script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/Jcrop2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jcrop_main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/Angular/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="jcrop_example">
    <img src="assets/img/floor.jpg" id="cropbox1" />
        <div style="margin:5px;">
            <label>X1 <input type="text" name="x" id="x" size="4"/></label>
            <label>Y1 <input type="text" name="y" id="y" size="4"/></label>
            <label>X2 <input type="text" name="x2" id="x2" size="4"/></label>
            <label>Y2 <input type="text" name="y2" id="y2" size="4"/></label>
            <label>W <input type="text" name="w" id="w" size="4"/></label>
            <label>H <input type="text" name="h" id="h" size="4"/></label>
        </div>

    <div style="margin:5px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" />
            <input type="button" value="popupZoneDetail">
    </div>            
</div>
```

**jcrop_main.js**

```
$(function (){

    // for sample 1
    $('#cropbox1').Jcrop({ // we linking Jcrop to our image with id=cropbox1
        aspectRatio: 0,
        onChange: updateCoords,
        onSelect: updateCoords
    });

    var i, ac;

    // A handler to kill the action
    function nothing(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };

    // Returns event handler for animation callback
    function anim_handler(ac) {
        return function(e) {
            api.animateTo(ac);
            return nothing(e);
        };
    };

    // Setup sample coordinates for animation
    var ac = {
        anim1: [0,0,40,600],
        anim2: [115,100,210,215],
        anim3: [80,10,760,585],
        anim4: [105,215,665,575],
        anim5: [495,150,570,235]
    };

    // Attach respective event handlers
    for(i in ac) jQuery('#'+i).click(anim_handler(ac[i]));


});

function updateCoords(c) {

    $('#x').val(c.x);
    $('#y').val(c.y);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);

    $('#x2').val(c.x2);
    $('#y2').val(c.y2);


    var rx = 200 / c.w; // 200 - preview box size
    var ry = 200 / c.h;

    $('#preview').css({
        width: Math.round(rx * 800) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * 600) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
    });
};



jQuery(window).load(function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion({autoHeight: false,navigation: true});
});

function checkCoords() {
    if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
    return false;
};
```

For the above code, I am not able to call `click` function for this code `$('#cropbox1').click(function()` when used with `AngularJS`

This is being used to crop the image but unfortunately it does not work. While the same works in a sample POC without including AngulaJS and `bootstrap.min.js`

Reference can be seen here - http://andrefarzat.github.io/ng-jcrop/
Please Guide.